# is there a way to animate one progressbar after another in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation

i want to implement a simple "skills part" with animation using pure Javascript , i want to fill only one bar at a time . how can i do that in pure javascript ?

Here is the HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Progress Bars</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- start a skill -->
      <div class="skill-box">
        <div class="skill-name">Python</div>
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="progress" data-value="90%"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end a skill -->
      <!-- start a skill -->
      <div class="skill-box">
        <div class="skill-name">C</div>
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="progress" data-value="35%"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end a skill -->
      <!-- start a skill -->
      <div class="skill-box">
        <div class="skill-name">Linux</div>
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="progress" data-value="75%"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end a skill -->

      <div class="test" data-value="75%"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the Javascript code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  let progressBars = document.querySelectorAll(".progress");
  progressBars.forEach((bar) => {
    console.log(bar.dataset.value);
    bar.style.width = bar.dataset.value;
  });
});
```

Comment: the width of each bar is 0% at the beginning . i want to fill the width of wach one to be equal the data-value attribute . i want to fill the first one untill complete then begin filling the second one and so on .

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait the amount of time the transition will take. So assuming your transition is 500ms wait before each progress 500ms times the progress your upto like so

```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        let progressBars = document.querySelectorAll(".progress");
        const transitionSpan = 500;// Transition is 500ms
        progressBars.forEach((bar, index) => {
            //Wait for previous transion to finish 500 * index
            setTimeout(() => {
                    bar.style.width = bar.dataset.value;
            }, 500 * index)
        });
  });
```

And your css should look something like this

```
  .progress{
        width:0%; // Set a starting with so transition will take affect
        height:1px;
        background:black;
        transition:width ease-in 500ms;
    }
```

Comment: @mrMatrix Happy to help! Please mark as correct if this worked for you

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry! JavaScript is a single-threaded language. This means that only one function can run at time. If I did a `console.log()`, the entire program will pause until that operation is completed.

```
for(i in progressBars){
for(let j = 0; j<101; i++){
 i.style.width=`${i}%`
}
})
```

should work in theory

Comment: Nope that’s not how it works. They will run in parallel.

Comment: Aren't for loops single-threaded? It shouldn't. Unless my understanding of a .foreach() is completely wrong. Either way, changed it to a for() instead of a foreach() just in case.

Comment: Nope. Double checked. Doesn't run in parallel.